# If $F$ is finite then is $\sigma(F)$ also finite?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $F\subset X$ be a finite family of sets of $X$. Is the sigma-algebra generated by $F$ ($\sigma(F)$) also finite?

I was trying to use induction: If $F$ has one element say $A$ then $\sigma(F)=\{\varnothing, X, A, A^c\}$

Suppose that it is true for a family of sets with $n$ elements. Know Let $F$ a family of sets with $n+1$ elements: $F=\{A_1,...,A_n,A_{n+1}\}$

$\sigma(F)=\sigma(G \cup A_{n+1})$ (where $G=\{A_1,...,A_n\}$). Then I was wondering if this is true: $\sigma(G \cup A_{n+1})\subseteq \sigma(G)\cup \{A_{n+1}\}$

Any comments or suggestions would be highly appreciated

Comment: $\sigma(G)\cup A_{n+1}$ isn't even a family of sets. Did you mean $\{A_{n+1}\}$ instead of $A_{n+1}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need for induction. If your sets are $A_1,\ldots,A_n$, then consider all the intersections $B_1\cap \cdots \cap B_n$, where each $B_i$ is either $A_i$ or $A_i^c$. There are at most $2^n$ such intersections (you may have repetitions).

Added: the $\sigma$-algebra is then formed by all unions of these sets, namely all $C_1\cup\cdots\cup C_{2^n}$, where each $C_i$ is either $\emptyset$ or one the intersections $B_1\cap\cdots\cap B_n$.

Comment: So the set of all the intersections of that form is a sigma algebra?

Comment: Not in general. Now you need to take unions of them, and it suffices to consider all $C_1\cup\cdots\cup C_{2^n}$, where each $C_i$ is either $\emptyset$ or one the intersections $B_1\cap\cdots\cap B_n$.

Answer (score 3):

So $|\sigma(F)| \le 2^{2^{|F|}}$ for a finite family of sets $F$, where $|A|$ is used to denote the number of elements in $A$.

Comment: thanks for your help @ncmathsadist. Where can I find a proof of this affirmation?

Comment: Think about it. If you have $n$ sets in a family, there are at most $2^n$ intersections of these sets.  Now the sigma algebra generated by this family contains alll possible unions from these subsets. There are at most $2^{2^n}$ of these.